# AWS ELB with ipv6 fails on online tests

Tags: amazon-web-services, ipv6, amazon-elb

I have an ELB with ipv6 AAAA DNS configured on route 53. The problem is that the tests I used tell me it's not ok (I don't have an ipv6 connection for testing):

[image]

AFAIK I don't need to configure nginx on instances for ipv6 as it should be handle by the ELB. But it's not apparently !

Note: I use the dualstack url in route 53 configs.

Comment: Load balancers in a VPC support IPv4 addresses only, see http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ElasticLoadBalancing/latest/DeveloperGuide/elb-internet-facing-load-balancers.html

Comment: There's no solution, really ? I mean I can't make an ELB out of a VPC!

Comment: If your ELB is in a VPC, then it will not handle IPv6 addresses -- even if you configure Route53 with an `AAAA` record with IPv6 addresses.  The issue is that the ELB itself, managed by AWS, doesn't listen on IPv6 addresses.  Only "EC2-Classic" ELBs _currently_ support IPv6 (and IPv4) addresses.  And unfortunately, AWS does **not** currently support assigning IPv6 addresses directly to EC2 instances, so you cannot run your own EC2 instance with a publicly accessible IPv6 address to workaround the issue.  You're not alone in this; many others would very much like AWS to support IPv6 properly.

Comment: What is a "EC2-Classic" ELB ? Never hear about that :o . When I create a new ELB, it's always in a VPC (I can't do one out of VPC)

Comment: @Nek I'm facing the same problem as you. How did you overcome?

Comment: @Keerthivasan there is **no** solution for ipv6 in AWS for now if you use load balancers in a VPS (most of cases).

Comment: @Nek you are absolutely right. AWS guys are not updating the documentation. It's very unclear that it is related classic EC2 or classic load balancer. I have retired my load balancer set up. Trying my hands on tunnel brokers now.

Answer (score 1):

Recently created AWS accounts only have access to the 'VPC' platform (look in your AWS EC2 Dashboard upper-right).  VPC-based ELB's do not have IPv6 capability.

Older accounts may still have access to the legacy 'EC2' aka EC2-Classic platform, where ELBs have IPv6. However, Classic does not have many of the newer EC2 features like the m4 / c4 instance types, enhanced networking, dynamic security groups, or ElasticSearch service (to name a few).

Since this is one place where Classic has a feature lacking in VPC, I wouldn't be surprised if the next ReInvent conference announces this feature.

Comment: Correct me if i'm wrong but what you basically explained is that because I'm a new user, I can't have ipv6 because of new infrastructures.

Comment: @Nek That's also how I read the answer. Which if it is true is ridiculous and should keep new customers away from Amazon.

Comment: That's why I really can't trust it. In addition their documentation is pretty clear: there is ipv6 support somewhere "Load balancers in EC2-Classic support both IPv4 and IPv6 addresses" – http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ElasticLoadBalancing/latest/DeveloperGuide/elb-internet-facing-load-balancers.html

Comment: @Nek yes, at this time new users do not have access to IPv6 ELBs.